# why only 1 java source file is able to write into the same file?

Tags: java, file, writer

In my StockTransaction.java, this runs first

```
try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:"+File.separatorChar+"transactions.dat"); 
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos); 
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osw); 
        writer.append(aStockTransaction.toString()); 
        writer.append("******This Transaction ends Here.*****");
        writer.flush(); 
        writer.close();}
```

Then in my brokerageAccount.java,this runs last

```
try {   
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:"+File.separatorChar+"transactions.dat"); 

        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos); 
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osw); 
        writer.append(brokerageAcc1.toString()); 
        writer.append("******This is end of File*****");
        writer.flush(); 
        writer.close();
        //System.out.println(brokerageAcc1.toString());

}
```

I tested with System.out.println to console, the output is fine.
But The end file only show the brokerAcc1.toString(), nothing for aStockTransaction.toString().
Why? How to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `FileOutputStream(filename, true)` in order to append to an existing file.